# Apache Drill - SQL Server plugin does not 'Show Tables'

Tags: sql-server, apache, apache-drill

Using Apache Drill,
I successfully created new plugin : mssql

Configuration:

```
{
  type: "jdbc",
  driver: "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver",
  url: "jdbc:sqlserver://99.99.99.999:1433;databaseName=ABC",
  username: "abcuser",
  password: "abcuser",
  enabled: true
}
```

But when i try to query again a table I get an error:

```
select * from mssql.ABC.dbo.TableName
```

Error:

> org.apache.drill.common.exceptions.UserRemoteException: VALIDATION ERROR: From line 1, column 15 to line 1, column 19: **Table 'mssql.ABC.dbo.TableName' not found** SQL Query null [Error Id: feba9fdb-1621-438a-9d7c-304e4252a41f on AA99-9AA9A99.xyz.abc.com:31010]

Even the below command returns no tables:

[show tables;](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yXiYN.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be like

```
select * from mssql.dbo.TableName
```